# R Boxpacker function not showing 3d visualization

Tags: r, 3d

I'm running the boxpacker package and the last visualization isn't showing when I set plotSolution = True, wondering if there was any way to fix it or simply show the 3d model in a different line? The package is located here https://github.com/delta1epsilon/BoxPacking

```
# create containers
c1 <- Container(length = 2, height = 2, width = 2)
c2 <- Container(length = 2, height = 2, width = 2)

# create boxes
b1 <- Box(length = 0.5, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b2 <- Box(length = 1, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b3 <- Box(length = 0.5, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b4 <- Box(length = 0.5, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b5 <- Box(length = 0.5, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b6 <- Box(length = 2, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b7 <- Box(length = 1, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b8 <- Box(length = 1, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b9 <- Box(length = 0.5, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b10 <- Box(length = 0.5, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b11 <- Box(length = 1.5, height = 1.5, width = 1.5)
b12 <- Box(length = 1.5, height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
b13 <- Box(length = 1, height = 1, width = 1)
b14 <- Box(length = 1, height = 1, width = 1)

boxes <- list(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, b14)
containers <- list(c1, c2)

# Box Packing
solution <-
  PerformBoxPacking(containers = containers,
                    boxes = boxes,
                    n_iter = 4,
                    population_size = 30,
                    elitism_size = 5,
                    crossover_prob = 0.5,
                    mutation_prob = 0.5,
                    verbose = TRUE,
                    plotSolution = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Which of many box packing packages (I'm guessing from github) are you using here? Perhaps adding a link will help others help? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry, the boxpacker is located here https://github.com/delta1epsilon/BoxPacking

Comment: I think you want `PlotPackingSolution(solution)`, if you have `rgl` installed. [Plot solution](https://github.com/delta1epsilon/BoxPacking/blob/master/R/plotcube.R), though there is a #TODO: think about case with 1-2 boxes, 1-2 containers [todo](https://github.com/delta1epsilon/BoxPacking/blob/master/R/PerformBoxPacking.R) that may or may not be resolved. Probably was. HTH

Comment: It says could not find function after I run the line, but on the github it visualizes a gif of a completed 3d model? I tried reinstalling rgl but it didn't seem to work as it was trying to update an already installed version.

Comment: I just installed BoxPacking and ran your code above. It printed out `Iteration: 1 out of  4 
  Chromosome: 1 out of  30 
  Chromosome: 2 out of  30 
  Chromosome: 3 out of  30 
  Chromosome: 4 out of  30` then opened two rgl windows, first one having the boxes in containters.

Comment: Would the problem be me using Rcloud Studio instead of Rstudio itself?

Comment: I'd have no way to test that. You have RStudio, try it. I was in R terminal.